# R, R², p-value and regression equation to multiple lines In R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

My code is a little bit long but this is the only way I found to merge all the data in one graph. Now, I need a way to add the regression equation to each line. Also, I want to add a legend to identify the data.

```
 ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCIB, y = RH), data = meanbasic, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "blue4",size= .4,lty=1,
              formula = y ~ x) + theme_light()+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle=90, hjust = 1))+ 
  ylab("Relative Humidity %")+xlab(expression(paste('UTCI ',degree,'C',sep ='')))+
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCIG, y = RH), data = meangird, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "royalblue3",size= .4,lty=1, 
              formula = y ~ x) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCIT1, y = RH), data = meantent, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "royalblue4",size= .4,lty=1,
              formula = y ~ x)+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCIT2, y = RH), data = meantent2, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "steelblue2", size= .4,lty=1,
              formula = y ~ x) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCT3, y = RH), data = meantent3, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "steelblue1",size= .4,lty=1,
              formula = y ~ x)+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCIT4, y = RH), data = meantent4, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "skyblue3",size= .4,lty=1,
              formula = y ~ x)+ 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCIP, y = RH), data = meanpanel, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "Turquoise", size= .4,lty=1,
              formula = y ~ x) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCIM, y = RH), data = meanmesh, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "darkseagreen3",size= .4,lty=1, 
              formula = y ~ x) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = UTCIS, y = RH), data = meansoild, 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "gold",size= .4,lty=1, 
              formula = y ~ x) + 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCIB, y = RH), data = meanbasic, color = "blue4",pch = 20) + 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCIG, y = RH), data = meangird, color = "royalblue3",pch = 20)+ 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCIT1, y = RH), data = meantent, color = "royalblue4",pch = 20)+ 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCIT2, y = RH), data = meantent2, color = "steelblue2",pch = 20)+ 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCT3, y = RH), data = meantent3, color = "steelblue1",pch = 20)+ 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCIT4, y = RH), data = meantent4, color = "skyblue3",pch = 20)+ 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCIP, y = RH), data = meanpanel, color = "turquoise",pch = 20)+ 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCIM, y = RH), data = meanmesh, color = "darkseagreen3",pch = 20)+ 
geom_point(aes(x = UTCIS, y = RH), data = meansoild, color = "gold",pch = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to help you without some of your data. I would suggest creating a small example data set and related code that reproduces your problem (perhaps 2 data sets instead of 8).

Comment: The easiest way to add a legend would be to merge all of your data into one data frame/tibble, even if this is only used for plotting the data and then deleted. May I suggest creating a new data frame/tibble containing what you want to store on the  and y axes and another column containing what data set it was originally from, and then passing the data set variable to the colour/color parameter in `aes`. (A simple way of doing this would be using a lot of `rbind` functions).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.